# VS 2010 Crystal Report

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I have a table in ms-sql

```
obm_FeeTable

FeeId int,
FranchieId int,
Amount Money,
ChequeNo int,
BankName nvarchar(200),
PaymentDate DateTime
```

when I want to display all collection in crystal report it don't show **Amount / PaymentDate**
when creating report, don't know why its doing like this.

Please help why is it doing like this. also how to use linq with Crystal Report.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you recently modified the table to add these fields? If so, perhaps Crystal doesn't know about them yet. To fix this, right-click inside the report, select "Database" -> "Log On or Off Server...". OPen The "Current Connections" item and select the one where your table lives. Click the "Log Off" button and then the "Log On" button. This will refresh Crystal's view of the database objects, and you missing fields should appear.

Another possibility is that the login you are using to access the table doesn't have 'select' permission on thos columns.

I don't think linq is applicable to Crystal, but the is a very different question. You should probably post it separately with more detail on what you want to do.

Comment: Hi Ray, no i have not changed it, even when making a stored procedure its doing same.

Comment: you say you are using VS 2010 - this version of Crystal is a beta - maybe there is something wrong there - have you tried it in VS 2008?

Answer (score 1):

To get fields to show up in Crystal's data connection, I often have to go to **Database->Set Datasource location** and then re-select the same table/view/stored proc I am using. Click the name of your table/view/Stored Proc in both the top and bottom windows. This tells CR to "change" the datasource from the old one (without new fields) to the new one (with new fields) even though they are the same view/table/proc. Then click update. This will reconnect your report with the same datasource, but will pick up any of the changes (new fields) in said datasource.

Yes, you can use LINQ with Crystal, it doesn't matter as long as the data you pull with LINQ ends up as something Crystal can understand. It needs to be stored in a DataSet or DataTable that Crystal can understand (you need to set the reportdatasource to your DS or DT, and it works great.